# GitHub Ci workflow ignores working-directory default

Tags: git, rust, github-actions

I have a "challenges" repository, which is a collection of markdown files describing activities to be done and also, in the same repository, inside a subfolder, I'm developing a rust CLI to correct and give tips about those challenges.

So the repository structure is:

```
.
├── .github
├── 01-terminal
├── 02-git
├── 03-algortimos
├── 04-elixir
├── README.md
└── cli
```

Then, I wrote some rust workflows to lint and check and then generate binaries of the CLI. The lint workflow is described as:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
    paths-ignore:
    - 'docs/**'
  pull_request:
    paths-ignore:
    - 'docs/**'

name: Rust CI

jobs:
  check:
    name: Check
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ github.workspace }}/cli
    steps:
      - name: Cancel Previous Runs
        uses: styfle/cancel-workflow-action@0.9.1
        with:
          access_token: ${{ github.token }}

      - name: Checkout sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install stable toolchain
        uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
        with:
          profile: minimal
          toolchain: stable
          override: true

      - uses: Swatinem/rust-cache@v1

      - name: Run cargo check
        uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
        with:
          command: check

  lints:
    name: Lints
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ github.workspace }}/cli
    steps:
      - name: Cancel Previous Runs
        uses: styfle/cancel-workflow-action@0.9.1
        with:
          access_token: ${{ github.token }}

      - name: Checkout sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install stable toolchain
        uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
        with:
          profile: minimal
          toolchain: stable
          override: true
          components: rustfmt, clippy

      - uses: Swatinem/rust-cache@v1

      - name: Run cargo fmt
        uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
        with:
          command: fmt
          args: --all -- --check

      - name: Run cargo clippy
        uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
        with:
          command: clippy
          # Set linting rules for clippy
          args: --all-targets --all-features -- -D clippy::wildcard_dependencies

  tests:
    name: Test Suite
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ github.workspace }}/cli
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.docker-prep.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
      - name: Cancel Previous Runs
        uses: styfle/cancel-workflow-action@0.9.1
        with:
          access_token: ${{ github.token }}

      - name: Checkout sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install stable toolchain
        uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
        with:
          profile: minimal
          toolchain: stable
          override: true

      - uses: Swatinem/rust-cache@v1

      - name: Run cargo test
        uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
        with:
          command: test
```

As can be noticed, I configure the options `defaults.run` as described on [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/setting-default-values-for-jobs) about the workflow syntax.

However, when this workflow is executed, it doesn't find the subfolder and then tries to run on the root folder, as can be seemed here:

```
/home/runner/.cargo/bin/cargo check
error: could not find `Cargo.toml` in `/home/runner/work/desafios/desafios` or any parent directory
Error: The process '/home/runner/.cargo/bin/cargo' failed with exit code 101
```

Maybe I'm setting up the `defaults` option wrongly? How can I setup the workflow to be runned inside `cli` subfolder?

Comment: Please verify the current directory and its contents by running `pwd && ls -l` before and after the checkout step.

Comment: Trying to run these commands before and after checkout result in `/home/runner/work/desafios/desafios/cli`. where `desafios` is the root folder, but it seems to be duplicated? Then the workflow fails with: `error: could not find Cargo.toml in /home/runner/work/desafios/desafios or any parent directory`

Comment: Side note: cancelling previous runs is a built-in feature via the `concurrency` keyword, you don't need a special action for that.

Comment: The [`jobs.<job_id>.defaults.run`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_iddefaultsrun) for the `working-directory` is only applicable to steps with `run:` , not those with `uses:`. unfortunately the actions-rs/cargo action itself does not provide any option to control the working directory. Consider to use a `run:` step instead.

Comment: Setting `with: { args: --manifest-path=cli/Cargo.toml }` on `actions-rs/cargo` may also work. Though if you're not using `cross`, I think the value of using `actions-rs/cargo` is dubious anyway.

Comment: I actually wonder if the `working-directory: ${{ github.workspace }}/cli` would work at the job level, as the `${{ github.workspace }}` variable is set through the `actions/checkout` which can only be executed through a job step (inside a job). In that case, the value set as default working-directory would probably be wrong / incomplete, wouldn't it?

Comment: As mentioned by @GuiFalourd, set up the working-directory parameter. You need to specify the path to the subfolder where your Rust CLI code is located. You have to set up the working-directory parameter for each step in the workflow.

Comment: Thanks for all these informations! I decided to change all `uses and with` of cargo-rs action to run manually cargo executable, so the `defaults.run` gots applied as I already had the rust toolchain installed after checkout